# MYSQL - Union SELECT & GROUP BY Not working

Tags: mysql, database, group-by, distinct, union

I have 3 table, *log, member, also guest,* but my log i stored as customer(user)'s **id** only, which is either their guest_id or member_id. So here's the problem, because they're from different table, I'm not sure how to join & group together their data.

**checkout_log table**

```
id        user_id      checkout_as
--------------------------------------
1         1            member
2         2            guest
```

**members table**

```
id        fullname
--------------------------------------
1         member01
2         member02
```

**guests table**

```
id        fullname
--------------------------------------
1         guest01
2         guest02
```

**What I wanted to Achieve - Result**

```
id        user_id     fullname     checkout_as
----------------------------------------------
1         1           member01     member
2         2           guest02      guest
```

---

Had tried following sql statement with **UNION ALL**, or **GROUP BY** , but had no luck.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT checkout_log.id,checkout_log.user_id,guests.fullname,guests.email,checkout_log.checkout_as
FROM checkout_log
LEFT JOIN checkout_product ON checkout_product.checkout_log_id = checkout_log.id
LEFT JOIN guests ON checkout_log.user_id = guests.id

UNION ALL

SELECT checkout_log.id,checkout_log.user_id,members.fullname,members.email,checkout_log.checkout_as
FROM checkout_log
LEFT JOIN checkout_product ON checkout_product.checkout_log_id = checkout_log.id
LEFT JOIN members ON checkout_log.user_id = members.id
) derivedTable
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: For my question also the incident, how was my table structure goign to plan? Because I feels very complicated to query and scare mess up my whole data also database. is it my above table structure are okay?please advise, this is my first time to plan a shopping cart database in my project, i'm still learning, please guide. Thanks!

Comment: The table names in your sample query do not correspond to the table names in your question.

Comment: Have you tried this without the group by? The way you're attempting to use group by is invalid and from what I'm reading you don't need it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry, edited the sample query table names.

Comment: @Lathejockey81 at first I had tried without group by, but it have a weird result with NULL value.

Comment: I see. Between the left joins and the way it's filtered that's certainly possible. I see possible duplicate data in your current structure. I would definitely merge the members and guests tables, and if possible use the checkout as field to differentiate them, but even better would be another column in the users table. If there's any chance of additional user types, then that is what needs to break out into another table. Unless the checkout as field is for historical purposes, it is redundant and should probably go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this with joins instead of union

```
select cl.id, cl.user_id,
       coalesce(m.fullname, g.fullname) as fullname,
       cl.checkout_as
from checkout_log cl left join
     members m
     on cl.user_id = m.id and cl.checkout_as = 'member' left join
     guests g
     on cl.user_id = g.id and cl.checkout_as = 'guest';
```

Comment: It work ! am also researching 'coalesce` this function @ mysql...cool!! Just needed to ask, is it my database structure are all okay? I'm worrying that in future having mass data then  the data will mess up, because of i separate 'guest' also 'member' as 2 table.

Comment: Your structure is okay.  I would be inclined to combined `members` and `guests` into a single table with a separate type column to distinguish them.